# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute (Google search results count)

Tags: python-3.x, attributeerror

In Python3 I try to get the search results count from Google for a random word, in this case 'test', with the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='GoogleResultsCount')
parser.add_argument('text', help='text')
args = parser.parse_args()

r = requests.get('http://www.google.com/search',
                 params={'q':'"'+args.text+'"',
                         "tbs":"li:1"}
                )

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
print(soup.find('div',{'id':'resultStats'}).text)
```

But whenever I try to run it from cmd, it says the following:

```
C:\Users\Peter\Desktop>gsc.py test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\GSC.py", line 32, in <module>
    print(soup.find('div',{'id':'resultStats'}).text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is this working somewhere other than the command line?  Are you sure the thing you are searching for is there to be found?

Comment: There is not id in the soup object called resultStats so find returns you a `None` object. which you then try to call text on. But none objects have no attribute called text

Comment: The id you are looking for is `"result-stats"`, not `"resultStats"`.